# how to change the primarykey manually on the YII 2 model

Tags: php, yii2

I tried to use this way, but the result is not complete column name.

```
class VMaterial extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'v_material';
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc$primaryKey
     */
    public static function primaryKey()
    {
        return "id";
    }
```

RESULT :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i' in 'where
>   clause' The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `v_material` WHERE
>   `i`='8'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to fix your problem:

```
class VMaterial extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'v_material';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc$primaryKey
     */
    public static function primaryKey()
    {
        return ["id"];
    }
}
```

or

```
class VMaterial extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $primaryKey = "id";

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'v_material';
    }
}
```

Comment: successful ! Thank you for your solution